# How to read uploaded excel file in postman?

Tags: python, api, flask, postman

I tried to read and analyze text in excel file in postman. Here is mycode.
import pandas as pd
from flask import request,jsonify,Flask

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import request,jsonify,Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])

def excel():
    data=request.files()
    df=pd.read_excel(data)
    textdf=df['Text']
    Text=[]
    for i in range(len(textdf)):
        Text.append(textdf[i])

    return jsonify({"Data":Text[0]})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=False,port=17002)
```

and I got this error.

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
```

Comment: data = request.files['file'], and then use postman post to send a file name with exact this key. I think it should work.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. If i want to know more about this, could you tell me the keyword to search in google?

Comment: I made this gist for someone: https://gist.github.com/nurely/68cb7cf6bfc2da881004d070c536f258